# Kendo UI - Angular - Formatting a date column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying a simple thing as displaying a date column in a kendo ui grid in Angular using the following:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="date" title="Date" type="date" format="{0:d}"></kendo-grid-column>
```

However the result is:

'2017-04-30T09:00:00'

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using the data received from your backend. It that case your should convert your date field to Date type manually.

```
return this.http.get("url")
        .map((res: Response) => {
            let result = res.json();
            result.forEach((x) => {
                x.dateField= new Date(x.dateField);
            });

            return result;
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in place of your format code: `format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"`. You have to specify which format you wish to use

Comment: are you sure? this works perfectly in mine and has done for a while now?

Comment: Why do you think I post?

Comment: are you sure it is compiling? do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: It does transpile and there are no errors in the console. Note that `format` for a number works, the issue is just with dates.

Comment: so should mine ('d' is a valid format for a date)... hence my post.

Comment: from what i recall, you have to specify the date format, as using `{0:d}` was a number format